# How to show function property holds for integers

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I want to show that for all integers $x$ greater than 1,

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor{\frac{4x^2}{2x-1}-\left\lfloor{\frac{4x^2-4x}{2x-1}}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor=3.$$

Upon graphing $f$, it's clear that this is probably true. I considered a monotonicity argument but I'm pretty sure that's not going to fly here.

Comment: Perhaps this may help:  proving $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is analogous to proving $y\leq x<y+1$.

Comment: @AndrewChin ah. Pretty sure that'll do. Was overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the inner floor.
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{4x^2-4x}{2x-1}\right\rfloor
$$
Using long division, we can reduce this as much as possible:
$$
\left\lfloor2x-1-\frac1{2x-1}\right\rfloor
$$
Now, since $x$ is a positive integer, $2x-1$ will also be an integer, so will not have an effect on the rounding from applying the floor function. So we have
$$
2x-1+\left\lfloor-\frac1{2x-1}\right\rfloor
$$
Now, the part inside the floor is between $-1$ and $0$ for all positive integers, so its floor is just $-1$. So, for integers, the inner floor is just $2x-2$.

So the whole thing is now
$$
\left\lfloor{\frac{4x^2}{2x-1}-2x+2}\right\rfloor.
$$
Again, using long division, reduce the fraction as much as possible:
$$
\left\lfloor{2x+1+\frac1{2x-1}-2x+2}\right\rfloor
$$
$$
\left\lfloor{3+\frac1{2x-1}}\right\rfloor
$$
$$
3+\left\lfloor{\frac1{2x-1}}\right\rfloor
$$
And finally, the fraction is clearly between $0$ and $1$ for all integers greater than one, so it's floor is just $0$, and we are left with $3$.

Comment: Love it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac {4x^2}{2x-1}=2x+\frac{2x}{2x-1}=2x+1+\frac 1{2x-1}$ while $\frac {4x^2-4x}{2x-1}=2x-\frac{2x}{2x-1}=2x-1-\frac 1{2x-1}$

The last fraction on the second is less than $1$, so the floor of it is $2x-2$.  Subtracting that from the first we get $3+\frac 1{2x-1}$.  The fraction is less than $1$, so the outer floor takes care of it.